# GraphQL data modelling - extended types (Prisma)

Tags: graphql, data-modeling, prisma-graphql

In my Prisma Data Model I started out with a basic User type like this:

```
type User {
  name: String!
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!
}
```

Now a User can have two roles: either as a candidate or as a user associated with an employer. If a candidate, the user should also have a set of applications and a set of qualifications, if associated with an employer it should have an access level and a reference to the employer.

First off, is there any way to extend basic types in GraphQL data modelling? If so, how would I go about doing it?

If there is not, I can see three different methods used, and I'm curious what are the pros and cons of each approach:

1. Having two separate types `CandidateUser` and `EmployerUser`, each with the fields `name`, `email`, `password`. I see two problems with this approach: The `@unique` tag on `email` is not reliable, and I would have to write a custom verification to make sure the field is unique across both types; and having a single login-function that takes email and fetches the users corresponding data is no longer trivial: it needs to do a lookup in both tables.

Like this:

```
    type CandidateUser {
      name: String!
      email: String! @unique
      password: String!
      applications: [Application!]!
      qualifications: [Qualification!]!
    }
    type EmployerUser{
      name: String!
      email: String! @unique
      password: String!
      employer: Employer!
      accessRight: AccessRight!
    }
```

2. Again two separate types, but with a `RootUser` containing `name`, `email` and `password`, and with `CandidateUser` and `EmployerUser` each having a one-to-one reference to a `RootUser`. This would enforce the `@unique` tag on the email field, but lookup would still be nontrivial.

   ```
   type RootUser{
     name: String!
     email: String! @unique
     password: String!
   }
   type CandidateUser {
     rootUser: RootUser!
     applications: [Application!]!
     qualifications: [Qualification!]!
   }
   type EmployerUser{
     rootUser: RootUser!
     employer: Employer!
     accessRight: AccessRight!
   }
   ```
3. Extending `User` to have the fields within EmployerUser and CandidateUser as optional parameters. This is a pretty simple approach, but I would need custom handling to enforce requiring fields (as in, I can not mark for instance employer as required as that field would not exist for a Candidate).

   ```
   type User{
     name: String!
     email: String! @unique
     password: String!
     applications: [Application!]!
     qualifications: [Qualification!]!
     employer: Employer
     accessRight: AccessRight
   }
   ```

I really want to ask if there is a better way of solving this. I'm still pretty new to GraphQL and not the best data modeler to begin with, but I'd greatly appraciate any nudge in the right direction :)

And if I do not have any other choice but the three I listed, which one would make the most sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is implementing an [interface type](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces):

> An Interface is an abstract type that includes a certain set of fields that a type must include to implement the interface.

```
interface User {
  name: String!
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!
}
```

This means that any type that implements `User` needs to have these exact fields, with these arguments and return types. So now your `Candidate` type can implement `User`:

```
type Candidate implements User {
  name: String!
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!
  applications: [Application!]!
  qualifications: [Qualification!]!
}
```

Interfaces are useful when you want to return an object or set of objects, but those might be of several different types. Have a look at the [**interface abstract type documentation**](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces) for more information.

---

**Update:**

Since this is a Prisma GraphQL question now, you should be aware that **Prisma does not support Interfaces or Union Types as yet**. [Issue #83](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/83) and [issue #165](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/165) discuss both respectively as feature requests.

However, there is this great article that discuss the workarounds for such approach:

[**GraphQL Interfaces (and Union Types) with Prisma and Yoga**](https://itnext.io/graphql-interfaces-and-union-types-with-prisma-and-yoga-7224f9e1d9ad)

Which boils down to 2 options:

> 1. Storing all data with optional type-specific fields under one type (the interface) in Prisma, and then splitting the data back between the primitive types in the app server.
> 2. Storing the data in each primitive type on Prisma, and stitching things for queries on the app server.

Comment: So if both Candidate and EmployerUser implements User, would email: `String! @unique` enforce that email would be unique across both Candidates and EmployerUser, or only within each field?

Comment: Oh I see now Prisma doesn't support interfaces so I guess I'm still stuck

Comment: @LarsHoldaas My bad thought you were asking a plain GraphQL question. (I just added the prisma tag), The interface types for prisma-graphql issue had been discussed here: [issue #83](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/83). There should be some workarounds in that issue.

Comment: Anyway it was a great answer! I thought my question was a general GraphQL question until I read your answer and then found out Prisma doesn't support it, so that's why I didn't tag it myself. I should keep this in mind for future questions.